# C# public class where T : class, Class, new() confusion

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract-class

I am new to C# and I am faced with a class with this structure:

```
public class SimpleGetter<TSubs> : GetterBase<TSubs>, ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>
    where TSubs : class, ISimpleSubscription, new()
{
    UserSubscriptionsResponse<TSubs> ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>.Get()
    {
        return ((ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>)this).Get(null);
    }

    UserSubscriptionsResponse<TSubs> ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>.Get(string userId)
    {
        return GetSubsResponse(userId);
    }
}
```

I need to pass userID to the get() function (if possible), but I am confused on how to do that. I have tried to do some research on this but I do not even know what this way of defining a class is called. I come from objective c where things seem more straight forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I do not even know what this way of defining a class is called

This is a generic class.

```
  public class SimpleGetter<TSubs> : GetterBase<TSubs>, ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>
    where TSubs : class, ISimpleSubscription, new()
```

which has one generic type parameter `TSubs`. This class inherits the  `GetterBase<TSubs>` and implements the interface `ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>`. Furthermore, the `TSubs` must be a reference type and must have a parameterless constructor, which implements the `ISimpleSubscription` interface.

```
public class FakeSubs : ISimpleSubscription
{
    public FakeSubs()
    {

    }

    // Here you have to implement ISimpleSubscription. 
    // You could also define any properties, methods etc.
}

// Now you could use your generic class as below:

var simpleGetter = new SimpleGetter<FakeSubs>();
```

Having created the above instance, you can call the `Get` method as [Tewr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61991/tewr), pointed out in his comment:

```
var response = ((ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<FakeSubs>)simpleGetter).Get(42);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just to complement Christos' answer and help you understand the syntax a bit better, let's break the class definition term by term.

[`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) - visible to all callers.

[`class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx) - a reference type (i.e. not a [`struct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx)).

`SimpleGetter<TSubs>` - the class name is SimpleGetter, and it is [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) with respect to the parameter TSubs.

`: GetterBase<TSubs>` - it inherits from a base class which is itself generic with respect to the parameter TSubs.

`, ISubscriptionsSingleGetter<TSubs>` - and it also implements the generic interface ISubscriptionSingleGetter.

`where TSubs:` - there are some [constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the type which the generic parameter TSubs must be of.

`class` - it must itself also be a reference type.

`ISimpleSubscription` - it must implement this (non-generic) interface.

`new()` - it must have a public parameterless constructor.